# Jump a new outlet from 3-way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, dimmer-switch

I have a Lutron DVCL-153P Dimmer 3-Way Switch for my ceiling. From the switch, I want to jump out to create a new outlet.

This is the picture of BEFORE and AFTER

[image]

Here is the picture behind the switch (Yellow Romex is new wire to Outlet)

[image]

**Problem**: When switch is ON, new outlet has no power. When switch is OFF, new outlet has power.

**Question**: Is there a way to re-wire this without having to start the jump from somewhere else OR replacing the switch to 2-way switch (assume 2-way will work)?

Thanks.

Comment: Explain "From the switch, I want to jump out to create a new outlet." What do you mean with "jump out" ?

Comment: I want to draw power from that switch location to create a new outlet near it

Comment: The wire that always has power is your Incoming, it is usually black and should go in the switch, Then it comes out (is switched) to the other side of the switch.

Comment: The 3-way Lutron is doing something which interrupting the power in a "reversed way". I even tried pigtail into the switch. So frankly I don't know how it make the outlet to have no power. My theory is that the new outlet has 2 hots and no neutral.

Comment: "dumb" switches don't have neutral connected to them, so you've supplied 'hot' and 'switched-hot' to your outlet. Now if you plug something 'large' like a space heater into that outlet you'll find that the lights which that switch used to control will never turn off.

Comment: See that red tape wrapped around the white wire coming out of the white cable in the top right? That's _NOT_ a neutral any more, it's a hot for your 3-way, running to the lights, while the black (if your labeled picture is correct) is your switched hot.

Comment: Or this? [Adding an outlet to a 3 way switch on 'far' end](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/161689/adding-an-outlet-to-a-3-way-switch-on-far-end)

Comment: Or this? [Can I wire a 3 way switch to a light but also have an always-hot receptacle?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101967/can-i-wire-a-3-way-switch-to-a-light-but-also-have-an-always-hot-receptacle)

Comment: Or this? [Can an outlet on a three-way circuit be made live full-time?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197721/can-an-outlet-on-a-three-way-circuit-be-made-live-full-time)

Comment: Or this? [Adding an outlet to a three way switch circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/228368/adding-an-outlet-to-a-three-way-switch-circuit)

Comment: **Switches do not have power**.  You can't tap them, as a general rule.  "I don't understand, my non-contact tester shows power there" no, power flows in *loops*. Switches only get half the loop because they only need to interrupt half the loop to make the light go out.  You need the whole loop, i.e. neutral (and no, whites are not neutral at switches).   In rare cases with 3-ways you can convert them to "smart switches" and part of this rearrangement causes them to have power there.  But it's not something you can rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted it's impossible to wire an outlet to code while keeping that switch functional.

In fact, what you've done is incredibly dangerous because you've supplied the hot to both outlet buses. Get yourself a [receptacle tester](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-GFCI-Receptacle-Tester-RT210/206517824) and you will see that the outlet is wired wrong.

Put it back how you found it and call an electrician.

---

This is a likely representation of your light's current wiring:

[image]

Notice how the power comes into the fixture? Then a single line is run to the switch so that it can operate a switched-hot scenario?